# Is there a way to have a virtual file in Windows XP that points to a file on the web? (without shortcut)

Tags: windows, file-management

Is there a program, or some way to have a file on the web, appear as a local file for the programs to use? Example: an image file on the web, show up as a read-only file in the Explorer, where I can open it with a program directly, without it being in my hard drive all the time, but on the web, but the programs and the system not being aware that it isn't a real file, since when trying to 'open' it, the file would be downloaded, and served to the program that tries to open it.

Answer (score 2):

If you type a URL into the box in the open dialog then it will get it from the web anyway.

Comment: Wow. I used to think that using this feature required the application to be aware of the URL and implement the HTTP interface internally, so would only work for certain applications.  But I see it even works with notepad.exe (in Windows 7). Do you happen to know if this is implemented at the OS level so it would work with any application?

Comment: I don't know - I use it a lot to add images to presentations and things like that, so I've never noticed it not work!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com) to achieve something very close to what you describe:

Dropbox is an online disk drive that is mirrored onto your computer. If you change the local file, it is immediately updated to the online disk. Now pretend that the local file is just a shortcut to the online file, and your goal is achieved.

Dropbox allows 2GB data for free; more if paid.

Answer (score 0):

You can also [mount an FTP site or Web site](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-map-a-ftp-to-a-drive-in-windows/). In this case, if the website supports WebDAV, you can also open the file for writing.